# Redirección 301 .htaccess POST

Tags: .htaccess, http, https

tengo en mi .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/contacto/intranet.mydomain-mydomain.com/api/public/api/project$ https://intranet.mydomain-mydomain.com/api/public/api/project
```

Ataco a mi API REST desde una página de wordpress pasandole parametros por POST el problema que tengo es que a esa URL me la llama bien pero me la convierte a GET

Hay alguna manera de que me haga la redireccion por POST con los parametros que le paso ?

Gracias

Comment: El código de redirección 307 mantiene el verbo http (POST en tu caso)

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias !!

Comment: De todas formas, si el acceso POST lo haces desde un navegador (en vez de desde un cliente REST), es bastante probable que el navegador muestre al usuario una advertencia del tipo "Los datos que has enviado en el formulario serán enviados de nuevo lo que puede causar efectos indeseados, bla bla"